# Mysql- How to change the rows into columns based on quarter column

Tags: mysql

i want to change the rows to cloms based on the quarter.

**My sample table is  as below**

```
Student name    subject standard    marks   quarter
Harry   Maths   class1  19  q1
Harry   Maths   class1  19  q2
Harry   Maths   class1  19  q3
Harry   Maths   class1  19  q4
Harry   science class1  18  q1
Harry   science class1  18  q2
Harry   science class1  18  q3
Harry   science class1  18  q4
Harry   social  class1  19  q1
Harry   social  class1  19  q2
Harry   social  class1  19  q3
Harry   social  class1  19  q4
Raj     Maths   class1  19  q1
Raj    Maths    class1  19  q2
Raj    Maths    class1  19  q3
Raj    Maths    class1  19  q4
Raj    science  class1  18  q1
Raj    science  class1  18  q2
Raj    science  class1  18  q3
Raj    science  class1  18  q4
Raj    social   class1  19  q1
Raj    social   class1  19  q2
Raj    social   class1  19  q3
Raj    social   class1  19  q4
```

**output should be**

```
Student name    subject standard    marks   quarter subject marks1  quarter1        subject marks1  quarter2    subject marks1  quarter3
Harry   Maths   class1  19  q1  Maths   19  q2  Maths   19  q3      Maths   19  q4
Harry   science class1  18  q1  science 18  q2  science 18  q3  science 18  q4
Harry   social  class1  19  q1  social  19  q2  social  19  q3      social  19  q4
Raj Maths   class1  19  q1  Maths   19  q2  Maths   19  q3  Maths   19  q4
Raj science class1  18  q1  science 18  q2  science 18  q3  science 18  q4
Raj social  class1  19  q1  social  19  q2  social  19  q3  social  19  q4
```

I have tried many ways like combining two select statements using where='q1' but, it is giving multiple rows.
please help me in this

***please don't mind about my table format hope u understand***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your output right, try

```
SELECT student_name,
       standard,
         'q1' quarter1,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q1' THEN subject END) subject1,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q1' THEN marks   END) marks1,
         'q2' quarter2,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q2' THEN subject END) subject2,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q2' THEN marks   END) marks2,
         'q3' quarter3,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q3' THEN subject END) subject3,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q3' THEN marks   END) marks3,
         'q4' quarter4,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q4' THEN subject END) subject4,
         MIN(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q4' THEN marks   END) marks4
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY student_name, standard, subject
```

Sample output:

```
| STUDENT_NAME | STANDARD | QUARTER1 | SUBJECT1 | MARKS1 | QUARTER2 | SUBJECT2 | MARKS2 | QUARTER3 | SUBJECT3 | MARKS3 | QUARTER4 | SUBJECT4 | MARKS4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        Harry |   class1 |       q1 |    Maths |     19 |       q2 |    Maths |     19 |       q3 |    Maths |     19 |       q4 |    Maths |     19 |
|        Harry |   class1 |       q1 |  science |     18 |       q2 |  science |     18 |       q3 |  science |     18 |       q4 |  science |     18 |
|        Harry |   class1 |       q1 |   social |     19 |       q2 |   social |     19 |       q3 |   social |     19 |       q4 |   social |     19 |
|          Raj |   class1 |       q1 |    Maths |     19 |       q2 |    Maths |     19 |       q3 |    Maths |     19 |       q4 |    Maths |     19 |
|          Raj |   class1 |       q1 |  science |     18 |       q2 |  science |     18 |       q3 |  science |     18 |       q4 |  science |     18 |
|          Raj |   class1 |       q1 |   social |     19 |       q2 |   social |     19 |       q3 |   social |     19 |       q4 |   social |     19 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8499/3)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself on name, subject, standard for different quarters along these lines :-

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl t1
  JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name and t1.subject = t2.subject and t1.standard = t1.standard
  JOIN tbl t3
    ON t2.name = t3.name and t2.subject = t3.subject and t2.standard = t2.standard
 WHERE t1.quarter = 'q1' and t2.quarter = 'q2' and t3.quarter = 'q3'
```

Comment: if suppose the data is having nulls, we may miss those